# What possibilities to use Flash will be there after EOL?

Tags: firefox, flash, adobe

As probably everybody knows, Flash is EOL after end of 2020. However, there are still many websites on the Net that contain Flash content. Most of them are Flash games, which are highly unlikely to be rewritten by their authors to use another technology (and I would still like to play them :)), however, just recently I accidentally stumbled upon a website that had menu in Flash (!) and was completely un-navigable without Flash turned on.

What will be the best approach to keep the possibility to use Flash? Personally I plan to make a copy of my current Firefox installation with Flash plugin before end of 2020 and keep it aside for accessing sites with Flash content, but what to do if I ever need to reinstall the OS (or replace the computer)? How to keep the actual binary that is downloaded by `flashplugin-installer` package for future use as it certainly won't be available for download anymore after end of 2020?

Also [Adobe's Flash EOL page](https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html) contains some wording that worries me a bit. It says "Flash-based content will be blocked from running in Adobe Flash Player after the EOL Date". Could it mean that Flash Player software is "time-bombed" in some way and will just stop function after December 31st, 2020?

Does anybody of you have any strategy or thoughts regarding approach to Flash EOL that you can share?

Comment: I have also wondered about the wording you mention. My theory is that sites which provide Flash dependent contents somehow query Adobe about the latest versions, and if so, Adobe will be able to effectively prevent you from accessing such contents after the year end.

Comment: this link may help (https://community.adobe.com/t5/flash-player/adobe-flash-player-end-of-life-past-dec-31-2020-how-is-blocking-of-flash-content-enforced/td-p/11184441?page=1) it's also where you should ask this question

Comment: I don't use flash but sites like cool math and other gaming sites will be shut down. I THINK, I do not know but I THINK that there has to be some "kill switch" in Flash, I do not know but that is what I think @raj

Comment: Install an older version of Ubuntu onto a VM **without network access**

Comment: A VM without network access won't help me in accessing Flash-based websites...

Answer (score 5):

So, using the link provided by @wraith3690-001 I am able to answer my own question :)

According to [this guide](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/flashplayer/articles/flash_player_admin_guide/pdf/latest/flash_player_32_0_admin_guide.pdf) (I recommend to download it for reference before Flash EOL), the Flash player itself will block content after EOL date. To work around this, one needs to create a file `/etc/adobe/mms.cfg`. Right now, if you put a line `EnableAllowList=1` into that file, you can basically get a simulation of what will happen after EOL date (as according to the guide, this setting will be enforced automatically after EOL). What will happen is that instead of Flash content, the Flash player displays an icon which, when clicked, leads to the Adobe Flash EOL information page.

To allow Flash content to run, you need to put in the `/etc/adobe/mms.cfg` file lines specifying which sites Flash player is allowed to access, in the following form:

`AllowListUrlPattern=http[s]://site.domain/`

If you want to specify both https and http for a site, you may put two lines for https and http, or you can use the following shortcut:

`AllowListUrlPattern=*://site.domain/`

You may also specify something like `AllowListUrlPattern=file:///` for local files, although it looks superfluous because Firefox does not support playing local Flash files via Flash plugin anymore, and standalone Flash player (I also suggest to [download it from Adobe](https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/32/flash_player_sa_linux.x86_64.tar.gz) while it's available) seems to always run file specified by command line or menu option regardless of `EnableAllowList` setting.

You can also put `EOLUninstallDisable=1` into `/etc/adobe/mms.cfg` file to suppress prompts to uninstall Flash that are mentioned on the Flash EOL page.

To keep Flash software for later reinstallation there are two options:

a) the `flashplugin-installer` package which probably most of us use now:

The package can be downloaded from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/f/flashplugin-nonfree/ (the current version as of this writing is `flashplugin-installer_32.0.0.414ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb`). However, this package contains actually (according to it's name) only the script that installs the plugin. The actual Flash software is downloaded during installation of the package from http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/. As of this writing, the current filename downloaded is `adobe-flashplugin_20200811.1.orig.tar.gz`.

If the latter won't be available for download, the installation of the package will likely fail. I suppose, however, that if you put the (previously saved) `.tar.gz` file into a correct directory before installing the package, the installation may succeed. However, I don't know what that correct directory is - I'm still investigating...

b) the alternative is to use `adobe-flashplugin` DEB package, which may be downloaded from the same location http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/ (current filename is `adobe-flashplugin_20200811.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb`). Looking at it's contents, it installs the plugin without downloading any external files.

For running local .swf files, I also strongly suggest to download the standalone Flash player from Adobe as said above.

Comment: Can you do me a favor and verify this is still the case?  The `adobe-flashplugin` package was torched in a way to make it a dummy / dead package now, and I don't know if the 'old' versions you refer to here are still going to work the way you expect it to.

Comment: Yes, the package has been removed. I have the old version still installed (I have locked version of the package in Synaptic when this new "dummy" upgrade appeared to prevent it from upgrading, which means removing in this case) and it still works for me.

Comment: Good.  Just wanting to make sure.

Comment: How can one go about obtaining a copy of the old functional package?

Comment: @riverofwind by googling for package filename, I found this site which apparently still has it: http://ubuntu.reduniv.edu.cu/CANONICAL/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/ (you should download the file that has "20201208" in name, not "20201231"). Rememeber to block this package from upgrading once you install it :)

Comment: Thanks raj, I got it working! Also found this guy https://github.com/7468696e6b/adobeflash-archive but couldn't get it working (maybe because I have snap Firefox?)

Comment: Is that deb package supposed to work for PPAPI Chromium as well?

Comment: @riverofwind From what I see, it looks like this package contains PPAPI plugin as well, but as I never used Flash in Chromium, I can't say if it works or not. Maybe you need to do something, eg. put files into some specific directories.

Comment: This guy's got the same problem as I do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65977941/chrome-flash-eol-on-linux-ubuntu