# Need help with removing Opera browser

Tags: apt, dpkg, uninstall, flash, opera

I tried to install opera from .deb file downloaded from their website. But it got stuck at 55%. So I closed the window. Then i discovered that it got installed and opened nicely. But after i couldn't run sudo apt update or install any app and even remove opera. When i run
"sudo dpkg --configure -a" I get this and it just stays like this forever. Can anyone help me?

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a

[sudo] password for xxxxxxx

Setting up opera-stable (73.0.3856.329) ...

dpkg: error processing package opera-stable (--configure):

 installed opera-stable package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1

Setting up pepperflashplugin-nonfree (1.8.6ubuntu1) ...

--2021-01-08 01:06:46--  https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/webservices/json/?platform_type=Linux&platform_arch=x86_64&browser_dist=Chrome

Resolving get.adobe.com (get.adobe.com)... 193.104.215.66
Connecting to get.adobe.com (get.adobe.com)|193.104.215.66|:443... connected.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html?platform_type=Linux&platform_arch=x86_64&browser_dist=Chrome [following]
--2021-01-08 01:06:47--  https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html?platform_type=Linux&platform_arch=x86_64&browser_dist=Chrome
Resolving www.adobe.com (www.adobe.com)... 103.15.244.233, 103.15.244.232, 2600:140f:7::1739:4c1d, ...

Connecting to www.adobe.com (www.adobe.com)|103.15.244.233|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

Comment: No. Because I din't get the right answer there.

Comment: how do i close my question?

Comment: no. I am not seeing any banner.

Answer (score 1):

Flash is obsolete now.

Run

```
 sudo apt purge pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```

to uninstall it.

Comment: Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 5107 (dpkg)  can't end this process

Comment: Reboot and try again

Comment: sudo apt purge pepperflashplugin-nonfree
[sudo] password for vvv: 
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

Comment: Is there any other way i can remove opera completely by deleting files?

Comment: Deleting files will make things worse.

Comment: But i get this after running the command you gave: sudo apt purge pepperflashplugin-nonfree
[sudo] password for : 
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

Comment: It was a bad idea to interrupt dpkg. Now I don't know how to resolve this simply.

Comment: can timeshift help me?

Comment: If you have a backup there, it can help.

Comment: I had back ups . Now lets try that.

Comment: @MugdhoMNS. Did you try the suggestion, i.e., running `sudo dpkg --configure -a`? If that still doesn't work, run `sudo dpkg -P pepperflashplugin-nonfree` and then retry `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me Kulfy. It worked

Comment: This seems to have happened because Opera's `.deb` file still recommends `pepperflashplugin-nonfree`. The latter ought to be turned into a dummy package in the Ubuntu archive. Please feel free to help pointing that out at [bug #1871471](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1871471).

Answer (score 0):

Reboot and then run:

```
sudo dpkg -P pepperflashplugin-nonfree 
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```