# Ubuntu 18 upgrade stopped on pepperflashplugin

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, flash

I was upgrading Ubuntu 16 to 18. During the installation process it stopped at:

*Setting up pepperflashplugin-nonfree (1.8.3+nmulubuntu1) ...*

I know that flash is no longer supported but I'm in the middle of the installation. I waited for an hour but nothing has change.

Any ideas?

Comment: My idea is, backup and reinstall, or troubleshoot.

Comment: @mikewhatever: Please see my answer.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thanks, but I don't care about flash, I am also not the OP, if you haven't noticed.

Comment: @mikewhatever: Flash is EOL. I noticed that you gave the OP a dubious advice considering the circumstances. Hence my comment.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to be patient. The package system is not broken, it's just stalling since a maintainer script is trying over and over again to download the plugin from Adobe. It may take several hours before it gives up...

There is a dummy `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` package in xenial-proposed. It's a pity that it hadn't made it to xenial-updates before you started the version upgrade (see [bug #1911463](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1911463)).

Comment: This post and the corresponding answer already exist... https://askubuntu.com/questions/1304984/configuring-dpkg-stops-processing-when-calling-an-http-request-to-adobe-flash-pl/1304992#1304992  (it'll just sit there and not fail - until the dummy is loaded manual cancel and remove of the package is a requisite.)

Comment: Fair enough @ThomasWard. This question and my answer doesn't add anything of importance.