# Flash Player on Latest Ubuntu?

Tags: firefox, chromium, flash, pepperflash

Hi I'd like to get flash player working on the latest Ubuntu under Chromium or Firefox. I've tried everything under the sun from Google search results to no avail. Is this still possible or is Flash for Linux completely dead? I've consulted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341428/how-to-install-flash-player-on-ubuntu/990925#990925) as well.

For

```
sudo apt install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash
```

for Firefox Flash I get

```
E: Package 'browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash' has no installation candidate
```

even though Canonical is enabled in Software & Updates.

Also the /usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree folder is empty when trying to copy libpepflashplayer.so to ~/snap/chromium/current/.local/lib for Flash for Chromium. When I try to enable flash via site settings in Chrome there is no option even though pepper flash is installed.

These steps are as per [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OcaVvPjDG4) with no luck.

As mentioned I've tried a bunch of other steps as well from other sites.

I could go into more detail but I suspect Flash is really freakin dead so there's no point... Is this the case?

Thanks!

Comment: Flash is dead for everything.  It was bad security when alive, now it is worst.  Unless you have a specific need and can secure the machine you use it on, but be better to bury it.

Answer (score 5):

Flash player is completely dead for all operating systems as of 2021. This is also stated in the [pepperflash documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/PepperFlashPlayer) There are some alternatives, such as [ruffle](https://ruffle.rs/), but these do not have full support yet.

However, you could try installing Ruffle:

1. download the Firefox extension
2. happy flashing! (only old  (ActionScript 1&2) flash games reasonably supported)

Comment: Thanks Gevaert. Ruffle has really spotty support right now didn't work with my target websites

Answer (score 1):

It is still possible to use Flash on selected websites, if you are able to find the Flash plugin itself anywhere on the Net, which can be hard, because it has been removed from all the usual places it was available to download from.

You need three things (at least that's what I use myself):

1. Firefox version no higher than 84 (install a separate instance of Firefox from your main browser into a separate directory)
2. the Flash plugin itself
3. a configuration file `/etc/adobe/mms.cfg` specifying URLs where use of Flash is allowed

I have written more about this [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278979/what-possibilities-to-use-flash-will-be-there-after-eol/1279175#1279175) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1616866/use-flash-player-after-12-jan-2021/1617236#1617236).

Also note: if you manage to find and install Flash plugin, don't let the system update it as "update" will actually uninstall the plugin. You may consider to lock the package version (eg. using Synaptic) to avoid update.

Comment: Thanks raj. Firefox worked.