# how to install adobe flash player on ubuntu 20.04 in 2021?

Tags: flash

I have Ubuntu 20.04
I have to run some Adobe Flash based web application on Google Chrome and Firefox ESR.
How to do this in 2021 when Adobe Flash Player is blocked by default and when binary was removed from repos?

Comment: (Or you pay Adobe or whoever to get some hacked version that doesn't have the embedded kill switch)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flash Player on Latest Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335878/flash-player-on-latest-ubuntu)