# How can I install Adobe Flash player on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: flash, adobe, swf

I need to work with a `.swf` file from the browser, but I have not been able to install Adobe Flash.

Comment: Flash has been dead for 5 months, so what you need to do is actually to find a replacement for Flash.

Answer (score 4):

You can't, Adobe stopped supporting Flash and all Flash games and other things that use Flash will be blocked.

Although you can still install Flash today but it is discouraged as unofficial packages can contain all kinds of bad stuff.

Comment: This answer is contradictory because you say you can't but later say it's possible but discouraged.

Comment: @qwr This is actually still accurate though.  Adobe has stopped supporting Flash, as have all web browsers that're mainstream.  While there are 'third party' unofficial packages that provide the same support, they're not trusted, so it's said that "Adobe doesn't work with it, but while there are third party packages for this, you should avoid them because of badness that is included in them"

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Flash player has ended support in like January 2021 but you don't really need it anymore as we are using something better that is HTML5.

Flash player can not be download anymore and most web browsers now stop support for Flash player so even if you could install it. It would be a waste of space on your drive and a waste of time.

Flash player has ended support because most websites stopped using it and it was a security issue. We also had to download Flash player.

HTML5 is preinstalled on your web browser and has better security. Most websites uses HTML5 now. But I do believe there is an alternative that allows you to play Flash games but not too sure.

Read more about the flash player [end of life](https://www.adobe.com/uk/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html).

Hope this helps anyone that is having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is still possible to use Flash on selected websites, if you are able to find the Flash plugin itself anywhere on the Net, which can be hard, because it has been removed from all the usual places it was available to download from.

You need three things (at least that's what I use myself):

1. Firefox version no higher than 84 (install a separate instance of Firefox from your main browser into a separate directory)
2. the Flash plugin itself
3. a configuration file `/etc/adobe/mms.cfg` specifying URLs where use of Flash is allowed

I have written more about this here: [What possibilities to use Flash will be there after EOL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278979/what-possibilities-to-use-flash-will-be-there-after-eol/1279175#1279175)

Also note: if you manage to find and install Flash plugin, don't let the system update it as "update" will actually uninstall the plugin. You may consider to lock the package version (eg. using Synaptic) to avoid update.

Also, if you can just download .swf file to your computer and run it locally, Adobe standalone Flash Player (aka Flash Player Projector) can still be downloaded and it does the job: https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html

Answer (score -2):

None of the current answers actually attempt to answer the question. It is apparently possible to still use Flash with Pale Moon browser by installing through Wine  from a third party. **I have not tried it and use at your own risk.**

http://www.microjogos.com/palemoon.php

https://archive.org/details/flashplayerarchive

Comment: Wine however bypasses a LOT of things, and Flash had actually supported Linux for **years** so your statement that Flash never supported Ubuntu/Linux is wholly false.  Also, links to things are not answers.  They get closed as 'link only answers' which are not full answers.